# Are $SO(2)$ and $U(1)$ two representations of the same group?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Maybe it's a naive question but, since $SO(2)$ and $U(1)$ are isomorphic, can they be thought as two representations of the same group? In particular, it seems to me they are two representations of the group of rotations in two dimensions: $SO(2)$ acting on a real vector space while $U(1)$ acting on a complex one.

Comment: If they are isomorphic as Lie groups they are identical in every non-trivial way (relabelling of the elements being a "trivial" way to distinguish them). In physics we often implicitly work in a particular representation that is of physics interest.

Comment: "Representation" is a charged technical term. You probably mean "realization", in which case your answer is "yes", hardly meriting a question.

Comment: `Thank you !!!!`

Comment: The answer is also yes for the technical meaning of representation.